# How do you assign a variable to a specific cell?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

In this case I have a simple user database to log usernames and passwords.

```
def load(*args):
options = {"level":0, "age":1, "cname":2, "reputation":3, "cl":4}
con = lite.connect(FILE)
with con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM data")

    while True:
        row = cur.fetchone()
        if row == None:
            break

        for i in args:
            if i in options.keys():
                indices = []
                val = options.get(i)
                print(val)
                indices.append(row[0][val])
return indices
```

This is to return a specific cell from the sqlite database; the error I recieve is:

```
    indices.append(row[0][val])
    IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: This is very broad. Please describe your problem in detail, and provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Just filter on the specific user and update

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("user.db")
c = conn.cursor()
pwd = 'hfrhbx63784hjf53hu&5'
user ='Nick'
c.execute(f"update users set password = '{pwd}' where name ='{user}'")
conn.commit()
```